# Redux Removes my old values from other container

Tags: redux, next.js

my problem is that certain action removes

Login_success action = sets userId and token. After login I set active menu item and it removes my old values as on the screen. Can someone explain why it even affects other container?

[image: Here is example]

PS: If I login second time, everything works fine(because the menu item is already set)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you share the code snippet for this

Comment: `case SET_MENU_ITEM:
     return {menuKey: action.payload, subMenu: null};`

Comment: And login_success is like this `case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            setCookie('token', action.payload.token);
            setCookie('user_id', action.payload.id);
            return {...state, token: action.payload.token, userId: action.payload.id, user: null, isLoading: false};`